# WPF event triggered when child user control is removed

Tags: c#, wpf, events, user-controls

I am deveping a WPF desktop app in C#.

My main aplication adds or removes user controls on the main grid depending on which buttons the users has clicked.

For example when a button is clicked:

```
gridMain.Children.Clear();
MyUserControl muc = new MyUserControl();
gridMain.Children.Add(muc);
```

In MyUserControl I have to write some files before user control is "closed", but I dont know where to do it, so I was thinking in doing it with some event.

Is it called any event in the user control when parent is clearing the children?

Comment: You may attach a handler to the UserControl's Unloaded event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such an event in FrameworkElement class:

```
public event RoutedEventHandler Unloaded;
```

You can subscribe to this event in MyUserControl.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no event being raised by the control or the `UIElementCollection` when `Children` is cleared.

You'll have to raise a custom event yourself or you could just call a method just before or after you call `Clear()`.